# How to fit pyplot image to given axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have axes with each axis limited:

```
ul_lat, ul_long = (45.499426, 9.119963)
br_lat, br_long = (45.434210, 9.235803)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_xlim(ul_long,br_long)
ax.set_ylim(br_lat,ul_lat)
```

Then I try to put a satelile photo as background and set up grid:

```
ax.imshow(image,interpolation='none')
plt.grid()
```

As a result I **can see no image**, only grid.
Now, If I remove limits:

```
    #ax.set_xlim(ul_long,br_long)
    #ax.set_ylim(br_lat,ul_lat)
```

I can see the image, though the figure scale is wrong and grid is plotted within this wrong scale:
[image]

See this thin grey line in the upper part of the picture - it is a wrong-scaled grid. The size of figure equal to size of picture what I don't want to (903x708). I want to use correct latitude-longitude axes same I tried to set up with xlim/ylim. 
What should I do to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `imshow`, you can specify the extent of your image to match your coordinates:

```
ul_lat, ul_long = (45.499426, 9.119963)
br_lat, br_long = (45.434210, 9.235803)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_xlim(ul_long, br_long)
ax.set_ylim(br_lat, ul_lat)
ax.imshow(image, interpolation='none', extent=[ul_long, br_long, br_lat, ul_lat])
plt.grid()
```

Comment: Thanks! I occasionly thought that extent is for absolute scaling.